# awk- empty Record Separator: "RS=" vs "RS='|'" vs "RS=(|)"

Tags: awk, bugs

I know that with `RS=` we can set the Record Separator to a Null/Empty string; however GNU `awk` also allows to define the RS as regex, so I decided to use `RS='|'` and I would expecting gawk to understand this as the same as `RS=` meaning that "***empty-string*** (or`|`) ***empty-string***", but that treat it as literal `|` character, while when I do `RS='X|Y'` that correctly recognize it's a regex (`X` or `Y`).

Would someone please explain what's happening in `RS='|'` that awk doesn't get it as empty-string?

I also tried `RS='(|)'` but this acts completely a different thing and I see it consider whole input as a single record.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition `RS='|'` **is** a literal `|`. Any single character RS is treated as literal for portability across all awks, otherwise you'd have a script with `RS='|'` behaving differently in gawk vs a POSIX awk. So a single char RS is literal while a multi-char string as an RS is a regexp if the awk version supports it, otherwise it's literally just the first char of the string (so `RS='.'` is always a literal `.` while `RS='.x'` is any char followed by `x` in some awks and a literal `.` in others).

By the way, in any other regexp context a single `|` is undefined behavior per POSIX but many tools will treat it as a literal `|` and the same goes for regexp repetition chars like `*` and `?`.

As for `RS='(|)'` - that means "null or null" which is the same as "null" which you could alternatively write as `()`. Seems like that'd match around all characters, I don't know why it doesn't. Different tools seem to recognize that regexp differently:

```
$ printf 'foo\n' | sed -E 's/()/x/g'
xfxoxox
$ printf 'foo\n' | grep -Eo '()'
$
$ printf 'foo\n' | awk '{gsub(/()/,"x")} 1'
xfxoxox
$ printf 'foo\n' | awk -v RS='()' -v ORS='x\n' '1'
foox
```

I contacted the GNU Awk developers (see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2021-01/msg00003.html) and 2 things came out of it:

1. You must not use a multi-char regexp that matches a null string as a Record Separator or as a Field Separator. If you do it will be treated is if the RS or FS does not exist and you will end up with a single record for the whole input (for RS) or a single field for the whole record (for FS). That will be explicitly stated in a future release of the gawk manual.
2. There is a bug in gawk 5.1.0 (maybe earlier too, I don't know) that is causing the terminating character to be consumed when the above statement was ignored. A fix has now been written for that and will be in a future gawk version.

Comment: Related: [Slurp-mode in awk?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/304457)

Comment: I came to upvote for the bug report and update on it, but I'd already done it.